# Modify form in default approval workflow

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I am using the OOTB approval functionality in my own workflow for an internal system I'm building.
However, SharePoint comes with very misleading info on the default approval form such as "This item will become visible to all users." next to the approve option.
[image: Approval form]

I would like to change this text as it is totally irrelevant to the actual process I have in place (when an item is approved the original user is notified, but no one else can see it). It will confuse users as it looks currently.

I've searched around but can't find much. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just delete the unecessary HTML text inside the form.aspx page?

Comment: So you want only "AssignedTo" to see the task?

Comment: @BrandonC. that's what I want to do yes, but I can't find the form.aspx page for the approval form.. any idea where it might be?

Comment: @Aanchal yes, but I've already done that, now I just want the form to show my own text.

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint designer?

Comment: @BrandonC. Yes - can't see the file though. Oh and I'm using Office 365 which may change things.

Comment: Hmm...can you add scripts to the webpage then?